# placing elements in one line html

Tags: html

I have following div and there are many html elements in side it

```
<div id="master">....<option><option>  <input type="file"/>.<div></div>...</div>
```

What I want is all the elements inside master div should be in one line and when the first line is occupied then it should start placing elements in second line

It it possible?

Comment: can you share your complete html code for better understanding ?

Comment: this html makes absolutely zero sense

Comment: Looks possible, better try it and see :)

Answer (score 2):

Try the css below to get all the elements inside the div `master` inline

**CSS**

```
#master > *{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

you can check a sample here..

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L1ud0w0g/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 #master {
width: 200px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

Or 
[Click here](https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/learn/tutorial/responsive-grids/)

Answer (score 0):

if you want all the childs to be in line wth eaach other you can do it by using `float:left` property.

check this code:(i think this is what you want)

```
<div>
        <select style="float:left">
            <option>--select--</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" style="float:left"/>
        <div style="float:left;position:relative;border:1px solid black">
            dummy Text
        </div>
        <select style="float:left">
            <option>--select--</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" style="float:left"/>
        <div style="float:left;position:relative;border:1px solid black">
            dummy Text  dummy Text  dummy Text  dummy Text  dummy Text  
        </div>
        <select style="float:left">
            <option>--select--</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" style="float:left"/>
        <div style="float:left;position:relative;border:1px solid black">
            dummy Text dummy Text dummy Text dummy Text dummy Text dummy Text dummy Text dummy Text
        </div>
    </div>
```